# Create Rows to the table where the data is missing for specific dates in power BI

Tags: powerbi, left-join, rows

I have a table with below columns in my dataset. We have monthly revenue for each resellers in this table.

For few resellers, there will be no data for some particular months, as they didn’t generate revenue on those months. I want to create rows for those resellers with the missing date and the revenue for those missing dates to be updated as blank.
Please advise how we can achieve this.

Current data:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Could somebody please help on this?

Comment: I can't even see what's the difference between your current data and expected result. To get this answered, you should update your question and make it clear what your data is (don't post it as an image), your schema, your efforts so far and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

For the missing dates you need to create a date table using the CALENDAR function like this:

Date table = CALENDAR(MIN(Date), MAX(Date))

This will create a table with a single colmn containing all the dates in your table with filled gaps (even if you don't have certain dates in your table). Then you need to create a relationship between your table and the date table.
When you use the date and the revenue in a visual lets say table or matrix all dates will be visible but the revenues will be blank (except for those that actually had a value in revenue).

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) I am afriad here that the blank values are not included!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34487069)